# What is the difference between Ruby and Ruby on Rails (web framework)?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to know more about the Ruby and Ruby on Rails.

How do you develop an application - what does an application structure look like utilising Ruby on Rails.

Where would you use Ruby?

Comment: Literally almost the exact same name

Comment: Google is your best friend, my friend. ;)

Comment: Ruby: Programming language. Ruby on Rails: A software development kit *for* Ruby. You should get a [good reference book](https://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails-4) to understand how they two relate.

Comment: I am mystified why this attracted votes for being "too broad."  It is answered succinctly in the exemplar that the question is now linked to as a duplicate.

Comment: @WayneConrad because of this: `How do you develop an application - what does an application structure look like utilising Ruby on Rails.`

Comment: Also, "where would you use Ruby?" is extremely broad. The questions asked could have been answered by searching and reading.

Comment: @theTinMan That was poor reading comprehension on my part.  I'm now only mystified that I missed that when I "read" the question.

Comment: Eh, I do it all the time. I blame age, stress and being tired.

Comment: Thank you for the answers thus far, The title is from a quora questions asked here,  I did not know how to succintly ask for guidance on how to develop a learning structure around how to learn the framework rails and to understand what Ruby does.  https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Ruby-and-Ruby-on-Rails-web-framework